# how to Integrate Magento content into your WordPress website?

Tags: wordpress

I am install this plunging but is not working. when i am add shortcode then his seen like this error:- "Unable to login to host with that username/password combination."

how i am fix it this issues please give me a suggestion..

Comment: try post in stackoverflow.com and wordpress.stackexchnage.com